# Order of queries with the MongoClient in Node is changing the order of execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I'm trying to build a registration api end point and I'm using Mongodb in that call to check 2 things:

1. If the username that's passed in already exists in the DB then send a status 500
2. if the email that's passed in already exists in the DB then send a status 500

If none of those conditions get triggered, then insert: `{"username": "foo", "email": "x@bar.com", "password": "123456"}`

This is the endpoint I'm using:

```
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
router.use(express.json());
router.post('/register', (req, res, next)=>{
    client.connect(async function(err, client) {
        let db = client.db(dbName);
        let users = 'users';
        var status = 0;
        await db.collection(users).findOne({'username': req.body.username}, (err, result) =>{
            if(err) throw err;
            if(result){
                status = 1;
                console.log(status)
                console.log(`username exists!: ${result}`)
            };
        });
        
        await db.collection(users).findOne({'email': req.body.email},(err, result) =>{
            if(err) throw err;
            
            if(result){
                status = 2;
                console.log(status)
                console.log(`email exists!: ${result}`)
            };
        });

        //catch any errors thrown from the DB
        await db.collection(users).insertOne(
            {'username': req.body.username, 'email': req.body.email, 'password': req.body.password}, (err, result)=>{
                if(err) throw err;
        });
        
        console.log(`status: ${status}`);
        if(status == 1){
            res.status(500).send('username exists')
        } else if(status == 2) {
            res.status(500).send('email exists');
        } else {
            res.status(201).send('User created!');
        }

        
    });
});
```

And the output I keep getting is:

```
status: 0
1
username exists!: [object Object]
2
email exists!: [object Object]
```

Which confuses me since it seems to be completing the insert before the finds complete?
(And I'm wondering why printing the result is `[object Object]` when printing it?)

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing asynchronous styles which is what is causing your issue. In older versions of node a callback style was used. When Promises became a standard feature many libraries updated their code to return a promise if and only if a callback was not passed to the function.

If you look at the documentation for find one at http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findOne you will see

```
Returns:
Promise if no callback passed
```

So, you either need to use callbacks properly and nest your calls within the callbacks or remove the callback arguments and use Promises + async/await proeprly.

For example using async await + promise value

```js
    const result = await db.collection(users).findOne({'username': req.body.username});     
    if (result){
        status = 1;
        console.log(status)
        console.log(`username exists!: ${result}`)
    };
```